# Jedi-vim throwing error unboundlocalerror: local variable 'module_path' when I am using go to definition for my python code on OSX Yosemite

Tags: jedi, jedi-vim

This is specially a problem when I am trying to find a function definition which is not present in the current file but present in the other file...
This is the error print that I see while trying to use Go To Definition
I am using vim 7.4 with.....Out of vim-version is pasted at the end. It has support of both +conceal and +python , -python3 ...If it helps...

```
File "/Users/atjha/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/evaluate/__init__.py", line 230, in _eval_atom
return self.find_types(scope, atom, stmt.start_pos, search_global=True)
File "/Users/atjha/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/evaluate/__init__.py", line 120, in find_types
return f.find(scopes, search_global)
File "/Users/atjha/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/debug.py", line 52, in wrapper
result = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/atjha/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/evaluate/finder.py", line 87, in find
types = self._names_to_types(names, search_global)
File "/Users/atjha/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/evaluate/finder.py", line 233, in _names_to_types
new_types = _name_to_types(self._evaluator, name, self.scope)
File "/Users/atjha/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/evaluate/cache.py", line 41, in wrapper
rv = function(obj, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/atjha/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/evaluate/finder.py", line 282, in _name_to_types
types += imports.ImportWrapper(evaluator, name).follow()
File "/Users/atjha/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/evaluate/cache.py", line 41, in wrapper
rv = function(obj, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/atjha/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/evaluate/imports.py", line 94, in follow
types = importer.follow()
File "/Users/atjha/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/evaluate/cache.py", line 41, in wrapper
rv = function(obj, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/atjha/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/evaluate/imports.py", line 252, in follow
return self._do_import(self.import_path, self.sys_path_with_modifications())
File "/Users/atjha/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/evaluate/imports.py", line 281, in _do_import
bases = self._do_import(import_path[:-1], sys_path)
File "/Users/atjha/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/evaluate/imports.py", line 316, in _do_import
**if module_path is None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'module_path' referenced before assignment**
```

Comment: let g:jedi#auto_initialization  = 1
212  let g:jedi#auto_vim_configuration = 0
213  let g:jedi#use_splits_not_buffers = "left"
214  let g:jedi#force_py_version = 2
215  let g:jedi#goto_definitions_command = "<C-]>"
216  let g:jedi#goto_command = "<C-]>"
217  let g:ropevim_autoimport_modules = ["os", "shutil"]
218  let g:jedi#squelch_py_warning =  1